# Performance while taking Join with a table used used for storing file

Tags: join, sql-server-2012

I have SQL Server with file-stream enabled. We are storing file at max of 50MB. But number of files can be huge.

Column that stores the file is of type Varbinary(MAX)

We are required to Take join of this table with other table on need basis. Though while taking join we are making sure we are not including the column with stores the file data.

Can i face performance issues while directly taking join the [Documents] table?
If so i will be willing to move data to intermediate table which will store the references for this table and will query this table only when i need to Upload/View/Delete a file.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You should take a look at new File Table feature of SQL Server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ff929144(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: I am using SqlServer  2012. And i think i am using same thing. Table Documents was created automatically when we enabled FIleStream. IT got     predefined columns etc. I am using same schema. IT got one column Name, we need to take join with this column. My concern is with Join. Can It impact  the performance in future as Documents table has one column(File_Stream) which in too large.

Comment: The file table contains an identifier (GUI) to the underlying fs stream, not the data itself, so there is not overhead caused by the document if you don't access it directly.
However, you say you have a "Column that stores the file is of type Varbinary(MAX)"...

Comment: Cool.. I think that answers my question. In Nut shell, Until I am not accessing File_Stream column (this column stores the file), performance is going to be same as querying a table which Ti self dont have File_Stream column.